# Remove password confirmation; devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using devise for authentication in my Rails 3.2.6 app. I had `password confirmation` first but now I want to remove it. How to go about that?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the password confirmation? Many users could make a typo when setting up their account and be unable to figure out what their password is without the confirmation check.

Comment: the ratio of typo to not-typo is significant.

Comment: @Aaron Password confirmations are annoying. In the rare case that a typo is made, all hope is not lost, the user can go through the "forgot your password" process.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just need to remove the `password_confirmation` field from your form.

<sup>[More info in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587139/72321)</sup>